# Merge MySQL multiple table delete statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I was able to reduce three delete statements (one of them with a nested select) into the following two non-nested statements (with `<list>` being a comma separated list of tids):

```
DELETE cs FROM cs, ds WHERE cs.did=ds.did AND ds.tid IN (<list>)
DELETE ts, ds FROM ts, ds WHERE ds.tid=ts.tid AND ts.tid IN (<list>)
```

The first should find all `ds.did` that correspond to the `ds.tid` in `<list>` and deletes all rows in `cs` containing these `did`. The second statement deletes all rows of `ts` and `ds` that contain one of the `tid` given in `<list>`. I tested the statements and they seem to work.

However I don't like the idea of transferring the same `<list>` twice. So I would like to do the same in a single statement.

Is there a way to merge the statements?

Comment: May be it's better to define ON DELETE CASCADE instead?

Answer (score 0):

If the ConditionID is the same for both tables, you should be able to use the [Multiple Table Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html)

Model :

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON (Table2.ConditionID = Table1.ConditionID)
JOIN   Table3 ON (Table3.ConditionID = Table2.ConditionID)
WHERE  Table1.ConditionID = ?;
```

Try with this query :

```
DELETE cs, ts, ds
FROM   cs
JOIN   ds ON (cs.did = ds.did)
JOIN   ts ON (ds.tid=ts.tid)
WHERE  ts.tid IN (<list>) AND ss.tid IN (<list>)
```